# onNavigationItemSelected set active item position title on actionbar

Tags: android

ActionBar

Let me try and explain this, I have a dropdown Actionbar with the selectable items, Home, Contact Us and About.

1. When the main activity loads, the default item shown on the ActionBar dropdown is Home. OK.
2. When I select the second item (contact us), the CURRENT ACTIVITY (main activity) sets itself as “Contact Us” then..
3. ..then the NEXT ACTIVITY (contact us) starts up but sets the ActionBar back to default “Home” instead of ‘contact us’

Please see my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private boolean mNaviFirstHit = true;
….
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
SpinnerAdapter sadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.actions, R.layout.dropdown_textcolor);

    // Callback
    OnNavigationListener callback = new OnNavigationListener() {

        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actions)
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {

              if (mNaviFirstHit) {
                    mNaviFirstHit = false;
                    return true;
                }

            if (items[position].equals("Home"))
            {
                System.out.println("Selected Home");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            }
            if (items[position].equals("Contact Us"))
            {
                System.out.println("Selected Contact US");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActionContact.class));
            }
            if (items[position].equals("About"))
            {
                System.out.println("Selected About");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActionAbout.class));  
            }
```

Comment: Add `android:label="@string/my_class_label"` to Activity you want in the manifest. The label is the title for the current activity on the spinner.

Comment: I think you miss understand, the spinner is the one with the incorrect label not the app label itself, if I may add, if I click on About, I can still select About again because the spinner thinks that it is still in Home, if I select About again while in About, the first About will have an "About" spinner while the second one will have "Home", if I click the back button (From second About to fist About" then the first About will have the "About" spinner and therefore preventing me from selecting About again which is what I want.